# Adding DataGrid to a GUI form via a separate class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have code similar to:

```
public datagridview dg = new datagridview();
//populate grid.

Form1 GUI = new Form1();

_dgv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 50);
_dgv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(630, 200);
GUI.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(_dgv);
```

This I was hoping, would place the datagridview on the GUI WinForm, but nothing shows up.

Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the DG creation and population is done in a seperate class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure the splitContainer1 is appropriately placed and sized? If it's too small, perhaps the DataGridView is located outside it's container (splitContainer1).

Comment: Yeah, that's all fine as I can fix the DG to the Winform if I do it from the GUI class.

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent of the dgv to be the panel:

```
Form1 GUI = new Form1();
        _dgv.Parent = GUI.splitContainer1.Panel2;
        _dgv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 50); 
        _dgv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(630, 200);
```

I know this theoretically does the same thing, but it works for me

Comment: No, that's not working for me.  Will have a look at it again tomorrow when back in the office.  Thanks.